# Why does child component re-renders even if useMemo is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

```
const Parent = () => {
    let [hitCounter,setHitCounter] = React.useState(0);
    let [clickCounter,setClickCounter] = React.useState(0); 
    const data= React.useMemo(() => {
        console.log("in useMemo")
        return hitCounter
    },[hitCounter]);
    return(
        <>
        <Child hitCounter={data}/>
        <input type="button" onClick={() => setHitCounter(hitCounter + 1)} value="Hit me"/>
            {hitCounter}
            <div><input type="button" onClick={() => setClickCounter(clickCounter + 1)} value="Click me"/>
            {clickCounter}</div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Parent;

const Child = (props) => {
    let data = 0;
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("in useeffect");
        data = props.counter;
    },[props.counter])
    console.log("in  Child");
    return(
        <div>
            The Hit counter value is {data}
            </div>
    )
}

export default Child
```

In the Parent component, I have 2 buttons Hit me and Click me. On click of each of them the respective counter gets incremented. So when I am clicking on 'Click me' the clickCounter gets incremented but hitCounter remains same. I am sending the memoized 'Hit me' count(hitCounter) to the child.

My confusion is why the child component is still getting re-rendered when clickCounter changes even though I am not passing it to child and have used useMemo for hitcounter(this is not getting changed).

I am using useMemo for hitcounter to make sure the child does not gets re-rendered when hitcounter is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

In response to a change in state, React will re-render *that* component with the changed state, and *all* children of that component. The props you pass to those children do not matter.

Consider this example:

```
export function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child() {
  console.log('foo');
  return <>Child</>;
}
```

Here every time you click the button, `'foo'` will get logged to the console. Here the `App` component has updated state, so all it's children render, too.

---

If you don't want that, you can use [React.memo](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) on the component, not the state.

> Wrap a component in `memo` to get a memoized version of that component. This memoized version of your component will usually not be re-rendered when its parent component is re-rendered as long as its props have not changed.

This is not a hook, it's a wrapper around component declarations.

```
const Child = React.memo(() => {
  console.log('foo');
  return <>Child</>;
})
```

With that change, the `Child` component will only render once for it's lifetime since it props could never change.

[See Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-p1bzst?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

---

That said, you rarely need to do this. You should only be looking at this if yo are having actual performance problems in your app. And even if you are, in my experience it's usually more due to your business logic than react's rendering performance.

Comment: Thanks Alex Wayne. I am just trying to learn hooks so I saw this one example I have added in codesandbox link at the end. If you will see in this we have App.js file which has a toggle button and it has one child which does not get re-render even though the parent(App.js) states changes. I have used usecallback 
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/8hlpr6?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx%3A5%2C39

Comment: What makes you think `Child` doesn't re-render in that link? It does, it's just that the effect doesn't re-run because it's dependencies have not changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip rendering a child component, you need to memoize that component itself. For example:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

const Child = memo((props) => {
 // ... same implementation as before
})
```

React.memo will skip rendering the child if none of its props have changed.

The other option is to memoize the element in the parent:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [hitCounter,setHitCounter] = React.useState(0);
  const [clickCounter,setClickCounter] = React.useState(0); 

  const childElement = useMemo(() => {
    return <Child hitCounter={hitCounter}/>
  }, [hitCounter])

  return (
    <>
      {childElement}
      <input type="button" onClick={() => setHitCounter(hitCounter + 1)} value="Hit me" />
      {hitCounter}
      <div>
        <input type="button" onClick={() => setClickCounter(clickCounter + 1)} value="Click me" />
        {clickCounter}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

As long as `hitCounter` does not change, this will reuse the same element, and thus react knows it has already rendered that element.

---

P.S, your existing code has some things that don't do anything of note. For example:

```
const data= React.useMemo(() => {
  console.log("in useMemo")
  return hitCounter
},[hitCounter]);
```

This code says that if `hitCounter` changes, it should run the memo function. That function simply returns `hitCounter` and assigns it to `data`. The same could be done with the code `const data = hitCounter`. And if `hitCounter` does not change then the cached version of `hitCounter` equals `hitCounter`, which again can be done with the code `const data = hitCounter`.

```
let data = 0;
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("in useeffect");
  data = props.counter;
},[props.counter])
```

This effect does nothing of note. Effects run after rendering is complete, so nothing is going to use `data` after you make this change. You've already finished rendering the component using `0` for data. You probably want:

```
const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      The Hit counter value is {props.hitCounter}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas Tower. I am just trying to learn hooks so I saw this one example I have added in codesandbox link at the end. If you will see in this we have App.js file which has a toggle button and it has one child which does not get re-render even though the parent(App.js) states changes. I have used usecallback in this example
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/8hlpr6?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx%3A5%2C39

Comment: `one child which does not get re-render` What are you doing to count the renders? If it's the line `console.log("FUNCTION WAS CALLED");` inside the useEffect, that will only tell you when the effect runs, not when the component renders.